# Unit testing a class that inherits from an abstract class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, abstract-class

My problem is that I want to stub a property in my abstract class, because my class in test uses that property. I'm currently using latest version of Moq.

My abstract class looks like this:

```
public abstract class BaseService
{
    protected IDrawingSystemUow Uow { get; set; }
}
```

And my class in test looks like this:

```
public class UserService : BaseService, IUserService
{
    public bool UserExists(Model model)
    {
        var user = this.Uow.Users.Find(model.Id);
        if(user == null) { return false; }

        reurn true;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how I can stub the `Uow` property. Does anybody have any clue? Or is my design that bad that I need to move to `Uow` property to my class in test?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your current setup won't work for one simple reason - `Uow` property is non-overridable and Moq's job is done at this point. [Cannot override, cannot mock](http://jimmykeen.net/2012/04/25/how-to-mock-private-method/).

Easiest solution is to simply make that property overridable. Change your base class definition to:

```
public abstract class BaseService
{
    protected virtual IDrawingSystemUow Uow { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use Moq's *protected* feature (this requires you to include `using Moq.Protected` namespace in your test class):

```
// at the top of the file
using Moq.Protected;

// ...

var drawingSystemStub = new Mock<IDrawingSystemUow>();
var testedClass = new Mock<UserService>();
testedClass 
  .Protected()
  .Setup<IDrawingSystemUow>("Uow")
  .Returns(drawingSystemStub.Object);

// setup drawingSystemStub as any other stub

// exercise test
var result = testedClass.Object.UserExists(...);
```

Comment: Thank you so much it really helped! It was a minor bug in your code snippet. Returns(drawingSystemStub) should be replaced with Returns(drawingSystemStub.Object). =)

Comment: FYI @jimmy_keen - Link for "Cannot override, cannot mock" broken

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case it's pretty straightforward. You just don't mock the `Uow` property but the `IDrawingSystemUow` service. So you can create a mock of `IDrawingSystemUow`, assign it to the instance of `UserService` via the `Uow` property and then run the tests (e.g. of the `UserExists` method).